# fluent-ffmpeg: Error reinitializing filters! Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument Error while processing the decoded data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to crop a single video.mp4 file in 9:16 aspect ratio by trying to crop. But I keep getting the following error:

```
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Here is my code:

```
import ffmpegPath from "ffmpeg-static";
import Ffmpeg from "fluent-ffmpeg";

const inputFilePath = 'myfolder/video.mp4';
const outputFilePath = 'myfolder/video-cropped.mp4'

if(ffmpegPath) {
   const cropFilter = 'crop=ih*9/16:iw';
    
   Ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
   Ffmpeg(inputFilePath)
    .outputOptions(['-filter:v', cropFilter])
    .output(outputFilePath)
    .on('end', () => console.log('Cropping complete!'))
    .on('error', err => console.error('Error while cropping:', err.message))
    .run();
}
```

Comment: @Christian the main issues were the .outputOptions(['-filter:v', cropFilter])
.output(outputFilePath) for some reason this caused the issue. I later used the spawn child process. I have posted a full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Christian Since it has been a long time I worked on this project the solution was not to use

```
.outputOptions(['-filter:v', cropFilter])
.output(outputFilePath)
```

since those two caused the issues. Instead I used something called spawn

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import ffmpegPath from "ffmpeg-static";
    
const args = [
                    '-i', `${localPath}/${fileName}.mp4`,
                    '-filter_complex', `
                        split [original][copy];
                        [copy] crop=${targetWidth}:${targetHeight},
                        scale=720:1280,
                        gblur=sigma=20[blurred];
                        [blurred][original]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2
                    `,
                    '-c:a', 'copy',
                    `${localPath}/${fileName}-cropped.mp4`
];
            
const ffmpegProcess = spawn(ffmpegPath, args);
            
ffmpegProcess.on('exit', () => {
    console.error('\n', 'Video cropping complete', '\n');
});
            
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpegProcess.on('error', reject);
    ffmpegProcess.on('exit', resolve);
});
```